# how to convert words from a string into dropdown list dataitems asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

in assign.aspx page i have

```
    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            str1+=li.Value+" ";
        }

    }                
    sql = " insert into assgnmovie values ('"+mvnm+"','"+thnm+"','"+date+"','"+str1+"')";
    SqlDatabase.Insert(sql);
```

}
now in booking.aspx page

```
protected void ddlMov_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select thname from assgnmovie where mvname='"+ddlMov.SelectedItem.Value+"'",con);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    ddlTheater.DataSource = ds;
    ddlTheater.DataValueField = "thname";
    ddlTheater.DataBind();
    ddlTheater.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("SELECT", "0"));
}


protected void ddlTheater_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select showtime from assgnmovie where mvname='"+ddlMov.SelectedItem.Value+"' and thname='"+ddlTheater.SelectedItem.Value+"'",con);
    String a = adp.ToString();
    String b = a.Substring(1, 6);
    ddlShow.Text = b;
     adp.Fill(ds);
```

how do i split the string and make the words as dataset for ddlshow.list???

Comment: are you stuck at how to get the different "words" from the space seperated string?  If that is the case: look up string.split(" ")

Comment: well,even if i manage to split the words,how do i make them populate the dropdownlist???

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
protected void ddlTheater_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select showtime from assgnmovie where mvname='"+ddlMov.SelectedItem.Value+"' and thname='"+ddlTheater.SelectedItem.Value+"'",con);
    String a = adp.ToString();
    String b = a.Substring(1, 6);
    ddlShow.Text = b;
    adp.Fill(ds);

    ddlTheater.DataSource = ds;
    ddlTheater.DataValueField = "showtime";
    ddlTheater.DataBind();
 }
```